# Get value of one column as string where other column value is specified string?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, select, datatable

Can I do this in C# with `DataTable.Select(filterStatement);`?

Or should I use Linq?

I have a SQL query that returns a DataTable dt2 with two columns, [Username] and [LastUpdated].

I want to get a string out of the [LastUpdated] column where the [Username] column is equal to a string.

Just in case this matters, both data types are set to varchar(50) in the SQL table.

I would post a picture but I can't yet, first post, the datatable is just

Username|LastUpdated
....admin2 | 2015-04-27...

In this case if I could just get the value of the second column where [Username] = 'admin2'.

I have tried the following in the C#:

```
string timestamp = "";
DataRow[] dt2result = dt2.Select("Username = 'admin2'");
timestamp = dt2result[1].ToString();
```

And I get

> > System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

I have tried to just use `DataRow dt2result = dt2.Select("Username = 'admin2'");` without the bracket [ ] but I get

> > "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Sytem.Data.DataRow[]' to 'System.Data.DataRow'"

I have tried different indexes like `dt2result[0]` and `dt2result[1][0]` etc, as well as `dt2result.GetValue(0)`

I know this is a basic question, but please answer it comprehensively!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you using varchar for a datetime field? (LastUpdated)

Comment: because I am brand new to SQL, and it was the first datatype I tried that would implicity take the 'DateTime.Now' value in the format it was in when I passed it from the C#

Comment: try using datetime field in sql, and cast it to DateTime in c#

Comment: Use datetime or datetime2 instead, and I would recommend you switch to using Entity Framework if you are new.  Or a SqlDataReader.  Don't use datatables/datasets/Sqladapters.

Comment: Is this a practice that would speed up pageloads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataRow dt2result = dt2.Select("Username = 'admin2'").First();
```

will get you the correct row (I assume).  Then get the correct column with:

```
var timestamp=dtresult[1].ToString();
```

The following should work as well:

```
var timestamp=dt2.Select("Username = 'admin2'")[0][1].ToString();
```

Comment: As others have questioned, not sure why you would use a string to store a datetime datatype.  Also why are you reading the data into a datatable rather than a strongly typed object via EF or even just using a SqlDataReader directly?  DataTables/DataSets are rarely the right thing to use.

Comment: You answered in seconds with what I was looking for. I had overlooked the .First() because I hadn't referenced Linq yet. I was limiting myself to just the c# which was frustrating. Thanks for the suggestions guys. I will look into SQLDataReader this week, it sounds like the right thing for a lot of the smaller queries we use (I work at a small chain of furniture stores)

Answer (score 0):

> In this case if I could just get the value of the second column where
>   [Username] = 'admin2'.

You have multiple ways of getting `LastUpdated` column value.

With your current code:

```
DataRow[] dt2result = dt2.Select("Username = 'admin2'");
```

You will get an array of `DataRow` back, you can check the length of your array and access the first row like:

```
DataRow firstRow = dt2result[0];
```

and to select value of second column you will need:

```
var lastUpdatedValue = firstRow[1];
```

Then there is a **LINQ option**

```
var lastUpdatedValue =  dt2.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Username") == "admin2")
    .Select(r => r.Field<string>("LastUpdated"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

I am using `r.Field<string>("LastUpdated")` since you have `varchar` data type for `LastUpdated` column. Just as a side note, it would be better if you use `DateTime` specific types for storing date and time values.